# How to get component name from service in Angular without using private API like view container ref

Tags: angular

i need component name inside service which calling method in service
console.log(this.vcr['_view'].component);
console.log(this.vcr['_view'].component.constructor.name);

Comment: `constructor.name` is not giving you right name after code is build using ng build --prod. because at build time code runs minified  and big class name converts to small names. thus you will not getting full-class name in production version of code

Comment: pass an additional parameter which hold the component name , this is the most simple solution

Answer (score 1):

[Demo stackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w8xgrn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponent-name.service.ts)

In service, you need to set property which is used to save your component name from your component class name. Thus, every component you have to class setter of property name from service and in template file call getter of property name from service.

Another thing, by using `constructor.name` you will not getting correct component class name instance in production. Because, at build time code runs minified and big class name converts to small names. thus you will not getting full-class name in production version of code.. For more reference go to this link of mine... [Dev.to](https://dev.to/gaurangdhorda/constructor-name-is-not-working-in-production-3ik4)

**service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class ComponentNameService {
  _currentComponnetName: string = 'default';
  get currentComponnetName(){
     return this._currentComponnetName;
  }
  set currentComponnetName(name:string){
     this._currentComponnetName = name;
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  setCurrentCmpName = "App-Component";
  constructor(private componentService: ComponentNameService){}
  ngOnInit(){
    this.componentService.currentComponnetName = this.setCurrentCmpName;
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="name">
   current Component Name is : 
  <h5> {{componentService.currentComponnetName}} </h5>
</div>
```

In every, component `ngOnInit()` you have to set `currentComponentName` and getting current-component name from any-where in app. Hope this will works for you.